# ImageMagick - batch file to convert

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a script that converts a PDF to JPG in the correct aspect ratio.

```
magick.exe c:\test\2.pdf -page A4 -set option:wd "%[fx:(4/3)>(w/h)?(4/3*h):w]" -set option:ht "%[fx:(4/3)>(w/h)?h:(w/(4/3))]" -gravity center -background white -extent "%[wd]x%[ht]" c:\test\2.jpg
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to create a batch file that will perform conversions for the input file PDF downloaded from the Internet. Something like open in 'convert.bat' where the result will be JPG in the specified location.
2. Is it possible to set a variable name of the output file

Comment: To your first question, ImageMagick will accept a valid URL as an input file name. Make sure you put it in double-quotes for Windows. For the second, there are many ways to generate particular file names. You'll need to be more specific about what sort of result you desire.

Comment: What if the URL and PDF file name are variable? As for the name of the output file, it is enough for the files in the indicated folder to differ. e.g. filename-1, filename-2...

Comment: The solution would also be to use the conversion function, directly from an open pdf file in a browser, eg Firefox. But honestly, I don't know if it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a batch file. I adds below. Maybe it will be useful to someone.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set INIMAGE="%~1"

magick ^
   %INIMAGE% ^
   -set filename:f "%%[t]" ^
   -page A4^
   -set option:wd "%%[fx:(4/3)>(w/h)?(4/3*h):w]" ^
   -set option:ht "%%[fx:(4/3)>(w/h)?h:(w/(4/3))]" ^
   -gravity center ^
   -background white ^
   -extent "%%[wd]x%%[ht]" ^
      "c:\test\%%[filename:f].jpg"
```